# Cross compiling uboot error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, bsp

```
/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

dirname: missing operand

Try `dirname --help' for more information.

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-ld: command not found

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

dirname: missing operand

Try `dirname --help' for more information.

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

dirname: missing operand

Try `dirname --help' for more information.

arm-eabi-gcc -DDO_DEPS_ONLY \
        -g  -Os   -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float   -D__KERNEL__ -I/home/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem  -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__         -march=armv5 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes      \
        -o lib/asm-offsets.s lib/asm-offsets.c -c -S

/bin/bash: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found

make: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 127
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tool chain path is properly exported then your problem is related to 32 and 64 bit mismatch.Perhaps you are trying to run `32 bit executable on 64 bit PC`.

you should install the package "ia32-libs"

Comment: ia32-libs is deprecated in the latest Ubuntu 16.04. It worked with the apt-get of equivalent libraries "lib32z1", "lib32ncurses5"  for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I followed this [link](http://linux-sunxi.org/U-Boot#Compilation) and I changed this:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- TARGET
```

to:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/full path/arm-linux-eabi- TARGET 
make
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tool-chain is not right set. After edit /etc/profile, you should execute the commond:source /etc/profile.
Or, after install the tool-chain, before doing make, execute:
  export ARCH=arm
  export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
After that, doing make

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to meet this error when you did install the toolchain such as arm-eabi-gcc, arm-eabi-g++, you can set the full path of toochain like this.

> export CROSS_COMPILE=/full path/arm-linux-eabi-

The full path depends on your enviornment on above.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not already stated in the previous answers.